# Changing frame and contentInset of UICollectionView in layoutSubviews() using IGListKit

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, iglistkit

I need to change the `frame` and top content inset (`contentInset.top`) of my collection view (which is a `UICollectionView`). The top inset and frame changes depend on the bounds of the superview and the content offset of the collection view, thus I put the inset-changing code in `layoutSubviews()`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()

  collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  collectionView.contentInset.top = new_inset_top
  collectionView.frame = new_frame
}
```

However, the collection view does not account for the new insets and the log shows the following:

> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView
>   minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content
>   insets top and bottom values.

How can I fix this to let the collection view displays correctly?

I am using IGListKit

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do all these inside of `layoutSubviews`.

in `viewDidLoad` implement it like following

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // let say you want 40px top inset
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Another thing is that, i don't get, why are you setting the frame in `layoutSubviews`. There is no need to set `frame` to change the `contentInset`.

Comment: I have updated my question. The content inset is not a fixed value in my case. It changes depends on the bounds of superview and the content offset of the collection view.